# My algorithm is only writing the first word to the file?

Tags: c++, file

I have written this code to write to a file in c++;

```
string Text;
ofstream Write_Test;("Write_Test.txt"); //Creating the file

Write_Test.open("Write_Test");  //Opening it for writing to, the ios::trunc at the end means it will open the file if it already exists, and overwrite any existing data with the new data.
while (Write_Test.is_open())
{
     Write_Test << Text;    //Write a message to the file.
}

Write_Test.close(); //Close the stream, meaning the file will be saved.
cout << "Done!";
```

But the problem is that it is only writing the first word of a string to the file...

So say if i assign the variable 'Text' to my name so 'Callum Holden', it is only writing Callum to the text file?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: This is not the code you are really using. Please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: "ofstream Write_Test;("Write_Test.txt");" *really* two semi-colons?? Really??

Comment: Please show a short, self-contained program which exhibits the strange behavior. Add the main function, and add the `#include`s.

Comment: Well, although this is clearly not the original code, but if you tried to show us the main points of you code, this "while (Write_Test.is_open())" is probably the main target; if you have something along those lines in your real code, that would be the problem, because you are performing loop while the actual file you are writing to is open, which is somewhat of an infinite loop.

Comment: This can't be the program you actually wrote, because the above has an endless loop.  Once `Write_Test.is_open()` is true, there's nothing in the loop which will change it.

Comment: Text is an empty string :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Text = "text";
    ofstream Write_Test("Write_Test.txt");//Creating the file

    Write_Test << Text;   //Write a message to the file.
    Write_Test.close();   //not necessary in this case   
    if ( Write_Test.good() )
        cout << "Done!" << endl;
    else            
        cerr << "Not done!";
}
```

Comment: You did forget to check the status of `Write_Test` after the `close`.

Comment: hmmm thankyou, but that has not worked. I am starting to think that maybe it has something to do with my code to assign the text variable:cout << "Write something: "; cin >> Text;    Is there anything wrong with that code?

Comment: It's much better than the code in the question though.

Comment: @user2799788 - yes, that will split on any whitespace. You should have put the actual code in the question.

Comment: Right that is the problem then, yes i really should of to be honest. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How would I make it so that it did not split on the white space?

Comment: @cpp The test is `if ( Write_Test )`.  You never test for `good()` (although for output, I don't think it makes a difference).  And of course, the test should affect the return code; that's the main reason for it.

Comment: @user2799788 It has nothing to do with splitting on white space.  You've not shown us the code which creates the problem, so we don't know what you're doing wrong.  (Input splits on white space, but output just takes the string you give it.)